# Converting Baillie–PSW test from Python to Java

Tags: java, python, bit-manipulation, primes

I'm trying to convert an implementation of the Baillie–PSW primality test from Python to Java.
I think I've done it mostly right, but there's a part where the answers start to deviate, and as a result the whole algorithm cannot detect any primes. This deviation starts to occur when the algorithm starts using the Lucas Primality Test.

Here's the original code for part of that test (part of [this repo](https://github.com/smllmn/baillie-psw)):

```
def U_V_subscript(k, n, U, V, P, Q, D):
k, n, U, V, P, Q, D = map(int, (k, n, U, V, P, Q, D))
digits = list(map(int, str(bin(k))[2:]))
subscript = 1

for digit in digits[1:]:

    U, V = U*V % n, (pow(V, 2, n) - 2*pow(Q, subscript, n)) % n

    subscript *= 2
    if digit == 1:

        if not (P*U + V) & 1:
            if not (D*U + P*V) & 1:

                U, V = (P*U + V) >> 1, (D*U + P*V) >> 1
            else:
                U, V = (P*U + V) >> 1, (D*U + P*V + n) >> 1
        elif not (D*U + P*V) & 1:
            U, V = (P*U + V + n) >> 1, (D*U + P*V) >> 1
        else:
            U, V = (P*U + V + n) >> 1, (D*U + P*V + n) >> 1
        subscript += 1
        U, V = U % n, V % n

return U, V
```

And Here is my Java counterpart:

```
static long[] UVSubscript(long k, long n, long U, long V, long P, long Q, long D){
    BitSet bitDigits = convert(k);
    long subscript = 1;
    for (int i = bitDigits.length()-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        U = U*V % n;
        V = (powerModulus(V, 2, n) - 2*powerModulus(Q, subscript, n)) % n;

        subscript *= 2; 

        if (bitDigits.get(i)){


            if (((P * U + V) & 1) == 0){
                if (((D*U + P*V) & 1) == 0){

                     U = (P*U + V) >> 1;
                     V = (D*U + P*V) >> 1;
                }else{
                     U = (P*U + V) >> 1;
                     V = (D*U + P*V + n) >> 1;
                }
            } else if (((D * U + P * V) & 1) == 0){
                U = (P*U + V + n) >> 1;
                V = (D*U + P*V) >> 1;
            }else{
                U = (P*U + V + n) >> 1;
                V = (D*U + P*V + n) >> 1;
            }

            subscript += 1;
            U = U % n;
            V = V % n; 

        }
    }
    return new long[]{U, V};
}
```

Can someone please help me? Here's [a runnable version of the whole Python script](https://repl.it/repls/RundownFoolhardyBusinesses), if anyone's interested.  And here's [a pastebin of my whole Java translation](https://pastebin.com/15ZpcJDU).

**PS** If anyone knows of a ready-made Java implementation of the Baillie–PSW primality test, I could just use that!

Comment: The simplest possible reason is an integer overflow. If your modulus is > 10^9, it's most likely the case. You may try using bigintegers to completely avoid this issue. Also `(long)Math.pow(2, i)` may possibly doesn't work (I'm not sure); just use bit shifting (`1L << i` should work, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place I can see deviations happening is in your translation of this line, and the three similar ones:

```
U, V = (P*U + V + n) >> 1, (D*U + P*V + n) >> 1
```

These are *parallel* assignments in Python, that is `V` is being calculated with the *old* value of `U` from before the statement.  But in your translation:

```
U = (P*U + V + n) >> 1;
V = (D*U + P*V + n) >> 1;
```

The `V` is being calculated using the *new* value of `U`.  A better translation might be along the lines of:

```
long old_U = U;
U = (P*U + V + n) >> 1;
V = (D*old_U + P*V + n) >> 1;
```

And again, this would also need to be done for the other parallel assignments.

Answer (score 0):

If you observe that the loop makes repeated use of the `P * U + V` and `D * U + P * V` values, there is room for improvement. You don't need the `oldU` variable mentioned in the accepted answer at all. Just calculate these two at the beginning of the loop, and use them later for both the conditionals and the calculations of the new `U` and `V` values. You win on both counts: using a separate value will make sure the assignments are no more parallel and you save a couple of unnecessary recalculations:

```
if (k.testBit(i)) {
  val PU_V = P * U + V
  val DU_PV = D * U + P * V

  if (IsEven(PU_V)) {
    if (IsEven(DU_PV)) {
      U = PU_V shr 1
      V = DU_PV shr 1
    }
    else {
      U = PU_V shr 1
      V = (DU_PV + n) shr 1
    }
  }
  else if (IsEven(DU_PV)) {
    U = (PU_V + n) shr 1
    V = DU_PV shr 1
  }
  else {
    U = (PU_V + n) shr 1
    V = (DU_PV + n) shr 1
  }

  subscript++
  U %= n
  V %= n
}
```

(This happens to be in Kotlin rather than Java but that doesn't make any difference.)